# SaerchView in ActionBar showing icon twice and not getting auto focus. Why is that?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment, searchview

I've a `SearchView` for a **fragment** in `ActionBar`. The problem is when I first touch the icon it shifts to the left (Expanded `SearchView`). Then I have to touch it again to get the text field. The below pics will clarify more.

### What I have already tried:

```
requestFocusFromTouch();
requestFocus();
setIconifiedByDeafault(false);
setIconified(); //Works but opens keypad even before touching searchview
```

### Codes:

**onPrepareOptionsMenu() and onCreateOptionsMenu() of Fragment:**

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setIconified(false);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

**menu_search.xml**

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>

</menu>
```

### Images:

**Initially:**

[image]

**Touched once: (Expanded)**

[image]

**Touched again: (Focused)**

[image]

Comment: You seem to be using a mix of native action bar (`SearchView`) and `appcompat-v7` action bar (`app:showAsAction`) functionality. **Choose one** and stick with it consistently.

Comment: I'm using `ActionBarActivity` from support-v7.

Comment: Then switch to `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`.

Comment: Okay that solved the problem. The `SearchView` is working good. But it looks old. What you suggest on using native `ActionBar` and `SearchView`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `appcompat-v7`, you need to use its edition of `SearchView` (`android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`). Mixing and matching things associated with the native action bar and with the `appcompat-v7` backport does not work in general.

> What you suggest on using native ActionBar and SearchView?

There are three major reasons why you might consider using `appcompat-v7`:

1. You want an action bar consistently, and your `minSdkVersion` is under 11, and so you need a backported action bar.
2. You want to try to adopt a Material Design-ish look and feel on Android 4.x, as `appcompat-v7` will give you an action bar, and some widgets, that look more like their `Theme.Material` counterparts.
3. You have run into problems with the native action bar implementation, perhaps on select devices due to manufacturer bugs, and you want to use a more independent implementation of the action bar to avoid those problems.

If none of those three reasons are compelling, feel free to use the native action bar and the native `SearchView`.